# Python Pulling Multiple Same Key Values

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list of dictionaries

```
{'datasource': 'firewall.vip', 'css-class': 'ftnt-virtual-ip ftnt-color-0', 'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3751'}
{'datasource': 'firewall.vip', 'css-class': 'ftnt-virtual-ip ftnt-color-0', 'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3750'}
{'datasource': 'firewall.vip', 'css-class': 'ftnt-virtual-ip ftnt-color-0', 'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3753'}
{'datasource': 'firewall.vip', 'css-class': 'ftnt-virtual-ip ftnt-color-0', 'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3754'}
{'datasource': 'firewall.vip', 'css-class': 'ftnt-virtual-ip ftnt-color-0', 'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 80'}
{'datasource': 'firewall.vip', 'css-class': 'ftnt-virtual-ip ftnt-color-0', 'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3756'}
```

I'm trying to pull all of the 'name' values out.

I've tried doing this:

```
new_list = []
parsed_lines = {}
for items in oldlist:
    parsed_lines['name'] = items.get('name')
    new_list.append(parsed_lines)
```

But it's coming out like this:

```
[{'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3756'}, {'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3756'}, {'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3756'}, {'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3756'}, {'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3756'}, {'name': '1.1.1.1--192.168.1.1 Port 3756'}]
```

Comment: Can you show us what you want the output to look like? I'm assuming you just want a list of values and not a dictionary. In that case, you can just say `new_list.append(items.get('name')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the name values in a new list, you can use a list comprehension:

```py
new_list = [d.get('name') for d in oldlist]
```